# How can I properly align two divs that fold atop each other when browser is shrinked?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm building a website template, more specifically; I'm making a universal CSS spreadsheet, and it's looking pretty good so far. But I ran into a big problem attempting to make a half sized `<div>` class whereas two would align side by side. [Check out my website so far](http://www.egxpt.com) (mind the swags) and notice how when you stretch the browser out far enough, they aren't centered correctly due to their sizes being `45%`. I've found that having two `.lefthalf` and `.righthalf` classes kinda helps, but more problems are caused than solutions. Also, making the browser too small causes both `<div>`s to go on top and below each other, but they are still floating `left`.

Could anyone find a solution where:
1. They don't fall back when the browser is expanded.
2. When the browser is too small to support alignment, they go above and below each other.

I hope I've made myself very clear and please help if you can.

FEEL FREE TO EXPLORE THROUGH `Inspect Element` ON [MY WEBPAGE](http://www.egxpt.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com) or Foundation for this issue, you don't have to implement those styles while Bootstrap/Foundation have a good grid system for you to use.
By the way, I solved this problem for you in the snippet.

```css
/*--Kairo Jewell--*/

/*-CSS Stylesheet-*/
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
    font-size:large;
    font-family:arial
}
a:link {
    color:#0077ff;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
a:visited {
    color:#0077ff;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:normal;
}
a:hover {
    color:red;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:active {
    color:red;
    background-color:pink;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
body {
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    margin:0px;
}
h1 {
    font-family:impact;
    color:darkgreen;
}
p {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:large;
    color:green;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
.goog {
    background-color:white;
    color:#222222;
    margin:5px;
    padding:10px;
    box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #aaaaaa;
    clear:both;
}
.goog2 {
    padding: 0px 5px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
}
.wrap {
    position:center;
    margin:0px;
    width:auto;
    height:inherit;
}
.center {
    position:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#header, #footer {
    position:fixed;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}
#header {
    z-index:99998;
    top:0px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:00aaaa;
}
#footer {
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:999999;
    height:20px;
}
#content {
    margin-top:75px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    float:top;
    width:80%;
}
span.bad {
    font-size:120%;
    color:red;
}
span.dark {
    font-size:120%;
    color:darkgreen;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.swag-content {
    box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #aaaaaa;
    background-color:white;
    color:#222222;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .goog2 {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="goog">
        <p>Swag</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="goog2">
            <div class="swag-content">
                <p>Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="goog2">
            <div class="swag-content">
                <p>Swag2Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag Swag</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="goog">
        <p>Swag
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>Swag</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 1):

for #2 problem this happened because you padding adds up to the size of the div and makes it overflow.
put this inside your .goog2 class.

```
.goog2{ 
       box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

for #1 problem try this put this inside your .goog2 class

```
.goog2{
       width:48%;
       margin:1%;
 }
```

if you dont want to have margin on each side of div and align each div on the side just make it 0 for each div.

```
 #div1{
       margin-left:0;
 }
 #div2{
       margin-right:0;
 }
```

Comment: if you dont want to have a margin on the side of each div. just make the margin of each side 0 for each div.

Comment: Thank you both! `margin:5px 1% 5px 1%;` worked even better. Also I dont know what `box-sizing:border-box;` REALLY does but it helped a ton. Check out my updated website if you want [link](http://www.egxpt.com)

Answer (score 0):

When the browser gets too small to support alignment, you could use a media query to change the CSS. Something along the lines of:

```
.two-col {
    width:48%;
    float:left;
    height:300px;
    background:#222;
    margin:0 1% 0 1%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .two-col {
        width:100%;
        float:none;
        margin:0 0 15px 0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/145fbw6k/

Comment: Thanks, I tweaked with that code a little, and used `width:inherit;` and `margin:5px` instead. Both of you guys really helped.